# How to convert URL field using Dozer bean Mapper?

Tags: java, dozer

I have the following classes and when I used Dozer Bean Mapper to convert `ProductEntity` to `Product`, and vice versa:

```
public class ProductEntity(){   
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private URL site;
}

public class Product(){
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private URL site;        
}
```

I get the following error:

> Internal error `[java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.URL.<init>()`

Is Dozer incompatible with this URL class, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: We are under the assumption that you have `public` accessor (getters/setters) methods for each of your properties, right? - Also, could you share your mapping `.xml` file (if any)

Comment: @ochi Yes, i have all public accessors.... but i can't find an mapping.xml

Comment: @MrPaulHenry - weird! Can you share how you are doing the mapping?

Comment: @ochi i'm using BeanMappingBuilder builder = new BeanMappingBuilder() instead configurarion by xml

Comment: @MrPaulHenry ok but can you share some sample code of how you are doing it? - maybe a typo somewhere? a missing configuration? or...?

Comment: @ochi I try to use BeanFactory to do this...i will share if it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done Dozer, but the reason you're seeing this is due to the way that Dozer maps objects.  It's looking to create a new object merely by invoking a no-arg constructor, and since `URL` doesn't have one, this is why you're getting that exception.

The way around this is to create an **identity conversion**:  map one instance of an entity to the exact same type of entity.

The way we do that is in 2 parts:

First, declare the custom configuration in your `dozer.xml` file.

```
<configuration>
    <custom-converters>
        <converter type="com.stackoverflow.URLConverter">
            <class-a>java.net.URL</class-a>
            <class-b>java.net.URL</class-b>
        </converter>
    </custom-converters>
</configuration>
```

Next, create a new `URLConverter` class which extends from `DozerConverter`.  The reason it extends from `DozerConverter` and not `CustomConverter` is for simplicity and type safety.

```
public class URLConverter extends DozerConverter<URL, URL> {

    public URLConverter() {
        super(URL.class, URL.class);
    }

    @Override
    public URL convertTo(URL source, URL destination) {
        URL result = null;
        try {
            result = source.toURI().toURL();
        } catch (MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public URL convertFrom(URL source, URL destination) {
        URL result = null;
        try {
            result = source.toURI().toURL();
        } catch (MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException e) {
           throw e;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The process here is fairly mechanical:

- Attempt to convert a URL to a URI, then convert it back to a URL.
- If there's any malformedness with the URI or the URL, throw it back - we shouldn't be dealing with a malformed URL at this state anyway.
- Otherwise, return the result of the converted URL.

Answer (score 1):

Add following statement in the xml configuration :

```
<configuration>
    <copy-by-references>
        <copy-by-reference>
            java.net.URI
        </copy-by-reference>
    </copy-by-references>
</configuration>
```